# How to center content inside collection view in exact center of shown ring view while scrolling horizontally (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set center the content inside a `UICollectionView` according to ring image in the center of the whole screen. Please check the image below. Any Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I think it's pretty unclear what you are trying to do. What content do you want to center? Where do you want to center it? Horizontally or vertically or both? Please add more detail to your question and take the time to write a good question before posting :)

Comment: I want to set center horizontal image while scrolling in collectionview to exact center of centeral imageview.

Comment: Look at the method `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset` that’s what you need.

Comment: Which is the image and which is the collection view? Are you using a storyboard or something? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The function you need is this one... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618007-collectionview

This function is called by the collection view when the user finishes scrolling. It provides the content offset of where the collection view will stop scrolling. (The proposed content offset).

You then need to take that offset and work out the nearest offset to place your cell in the middle of the screen.

Something like, find the item that will be closest to the middle. Work out how far away from the middle it is so you know how much to shift it by. Then apply that shift to the proposed content offset.

This will allow your collection view to decelerate naturally but always stop at the point that you want it to stop.